# Can I extract type from array?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Here is my goal, I'm wondering is it possible to create a `PickFromArray` type like this?

```
type FooBar = { foo: string, bar: number, foobar: string }
type Result = PickFromArray<FooBar,['foo','foobar']> // {foo: string, foobar: string}
```

Comment: You may answer your own question and mark it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

```
type PickFromArray<T,U extends any[]> = Pick<T, U[number]>
```